# systemctl node script fails due to es6 syntax

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, systemctl

I am trying to run a node script as a systemctl service. Checking the error logs I can see the script starts but fails because it does not recognise es6 syntax.
`Error: import {getRaces} from './getRaces.js Syntax error: unexpected token {`

Originally, running the script in its directory gave the same error, so I used `npm install @babel/runtime` and it fixed it when running it in the directory, but running the script as a systemctl service still gives the same error as before.

The contents of the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Race scheduler

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/app-scripts
ExecStart=node race_scheduler.js
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Ensure you have a recent enough version of Node and use `.mjs` if you want to use ES modules: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html

Comment: It is node 14.17. I tried changing to ```.mjs``` and it gave errors due to using await keyword. It runs fine using ```node race_scheduler.js``` when in the directory, only fails when using systemctl.

Comment: Basically, how do I ensure that the systemctl service will run it in the exact same way as if I ```cd /home/app-scripts node race_scheduler.js``` which works at the moment.

Comment: The problem was that systemd runs the wrong version of node. I checked the location of the node binary using ```which node``` and then used that in ExecStart